# What is the best way to organize Apache (site-custom) config files without affecting the default ones?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, centos

This is a CentOS box, so some of the layout is different than Ubuntu.

If we look at the httpd.conf file, it expects to get the locally defined config files (virtual hosts, etc) from /etc/httpd/conf.d:

```
[raub@webbie ~]$ fgrep Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
[raub@webbie ~]$
```

Now [the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) suggest to use a separate directory for configs specific to virtual hosts,

```
IncludeOptional conf/vhosts/*/*.conf
```

but I do not want to edit the httpd.conf file in case it gets overwritten during an upgrade or some other event. So, what would be the best way to fake that without modifying the original files? Best I could come up is a /etc/httpd/conf.d/zvirtualhosts.conf file (named so it is only read as close to the end as possible) which only have the above include statement, but it feels a bit kludgy. Are there more elegant/cleaner solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Short of using one or more symbolic links (which honestly feels less preferable to me), I think your proposed solution is about as elegant as you're likely to get (at least if your are unwilling to edit any configuration files).

Answer (score 0):

RHEL/Centos docs suggest to use different config files that Ubuntu/Debian: 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-web_servers#s2-apache-virtualhosts

If you worry about configuration files overwrites, you can always use some configuration management tool like Puppet.